# manipulating data set in R

Tags: r

How can I manipulate the data that I only have the rows where Producttype is 3? I want to find out the median price of all the Producttypes 3.

This is the data:

```
library(data.table)
sales <- data.table(Customer = c(192,964,929,345,898,477,705,804,188,231,780,611,420,816,171,212,504,526,471,979,524,410,557,152,417,359,435,820,305,268,763,194,757,475,351,933,805,687,813,880,798,327,602,710,785,840,446,891,165,662),
                    Producttype = c(1,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,3,1),
                    Price = c(469,721,856,956,554,188,429,502,507,669,427,582,574,992,418,835,652,983,149,917,370,617,876,337,663,252,599,949,915,556,313,842,892,724,415,307,900,114,439,456,541,261,881,757,199,308,958,374,409,738),
                    Quarter = c(2,3,3,4,4,1,4,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,2,2,2,1,4,3,3,1,1,1,3,1,1))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do `sales[Producttype == 3, median(Price)]`

Comment: You expect that someone can give you the code and explain it? Please edit your question so it dosent seem to demand an answer, even though you probably don’t mean to.

Answer (score 3):

Your median sales price for all product type 3 is 576.5.

```
library(data.table)
sales <- data.table(Customer = c(192,964,929,345,898,477,705,804,188,231,780,611,420,816,171,212,504,526,471,979,524,410,557,152,417,359,435,820,305,268,763,194,757,475,351,933,805,687,813,880,798,327,602,710,785,840,446,891,165,662),
                    Producttype = c(1,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,3,1),
                    Price = c(469,721,856,956,554,188,429,502,507,669,427,582,574,992,418,835,652,983,149,917,370,617,876,337,663,252,599,949,915,556,313,842,892,724,415,307,900,114,439,456,541,261,881,757,199,308,958,374,409,738),
                    Quarter = c(2,3,3,4,4,1,4,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,2,2,2,1,4,3,3,1,1,1,3,1,1))

# Filter rows where Producttype is 3
sales_subset <-  sales[sales$Producttype==3]

# Calculate median price 
median(sales_subset$Price)
```